# clone() method implementation in PriorityQueue

Tags: java, priority-queue

For my data structures class our assignment is to implement a PriorityQueue class that uses an already created array based queue.  Everything is working in the PriorityQueue class except for the clone method.  When the clone method is activated nothing is returned even though there is data in the queue that is being cloned.   The PriorityQueue class uses an array of ArrayQueues.  I just copied the constructor and clone method from my class.

Thanks for the help

```
private ArrayQueue<E>[] queues;
private int manyItems;
private int highest;

public PriorityQueueArray(int a_highest) {
    manyItems = 0;
    highest = a_highest;
    queues = new ArrayQueue[a_highest+1];
    for(int i = 0; i <= a_highest; i++) {
        queues[i] = new ArrayQueue();
    }
}

public PriorityQueueArray<E> clone() {
    PriorityQueueArray<E> answer;

    try{
        answer = (PriorityQueueArray<E>) super.clone();
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        // This exception should not occur. But if it does, it would probably indicate a
        // programming error that made super.clone unavailable. The most common error
        // The most common error would be forgetting the "Implements Cloneable"
        // clause at the start of this class.
        throw new RuntimeException
           ("This class does not implement Cloneable");         
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= highest; i++) {
        answer.queues[i] = queues[i].clone();
    }   
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: what does "nothing is returned" means? Null or empty array for the queues?

Comment: When returning a PriorityQueueArray object the instance variable manyItems returns the correct number from the object that is being cloned (5) but the items (queues[]) in the PriorityQueueArray that are being cloned are not being copied to the answer variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is that `queues` is not being cloned properly.  Try this:

```
public PriorityQueueArray<E> clone() {
    PriorityQueueArray<E> answer;
    answer.manyItems = manyItems;
    answer.highest = highest;
    answer.queues = new ArrayQueue<E>[queues.length]; // This is the key!
    for (int i = 0; i <= highest; i++) {
        answer.queues[i] = queues[i].clone();
    }   
    return answer;
}
```

Your original code relies on `super.clone()` to do a lot of the work, but the default version of that method does a shallow clone, and that doesn't make a copy of the `queues` array.  So you end up with a "clone" that shares its queue array with the original. That will mean that the `ArrayQueue` instances will be shared, and strange things will happen ...

(Given that we need to manually `new` the `queues` array, it simplest to manually copy the other 2 fields as well.)

We'd need to see your unit test to figure out how / why this results in the symptoms you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephen, that was the key!  I wasn't creating a new ArrayQueue for the clone.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
@Override
public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
  // your method here.
  ...
}
```

as the method signature. It looks as though you are not correctly overriding the clone method by using a slightly different signature. See [information](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html) on the @Override annotation on how to use the compiler to pick up similar sorts of problems.

See [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) for more details on the clone method.

Comment: While it is good practice to use @Override, I don't think that the method signature is the problem here.  Remember that the signature that counts for the purpose of determining if this is an overload is the method name + the argument types.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the declaration of Priority Queue it does not implement the clonable interface.

```
public class PriorityQueue<E> extends AbstractQueue<E> implements Serializable
```